# Prefered way to manage Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

What's prefered (or best practice for migration), run artisan migration everytime we created a new migration file, or after we created some?

**Everytime:**

- Create migration file
- Run `php artisan migrate`
- Create another migration file
- Run `php artisan migrate`
- Create another migration file
- Run `php artisan migrate`
- etc

**After created some:**

- Create migration file
- Create another migration file
- Create another migration file
- Run `php artisan migrate`
- etc

Comment: There is no preferred way but I prefer second one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no preferred way of creating migrations, it's as you like and depends on your project.